# Consistency of solutions to linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In reading [this](http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-LC.html), I came across:
"Suppose [*A*] is the augmented matrix of a system of linear equations with *n* variables. Suppose also that *B* is a row-equivalent matrix in reduced row-echelon form with *r* nonzero rows. Then the system of equations is inconsistent if and only if column *n*+1 of *B* is a pivot column."

I'm not certain which value *r* is meant to indicate in this context; to what does *r* refer?

Comment: If I'm reading it correctly, $r$ is arbitrary and was only first introduced in that sentence and not before.  $r$ here is the number of nonzero rows that $B$ has, and will be equal to the "rank" of $B$ (either directly by definition, or it can be shown to be equal depending on your definition used).

Comment: Consider for examples: $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&2\\0&0&0&0\end{array}\right]$ is a consistent system (*one which happens to have infinitely many solutions*) while $\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}1&0&0&1\\0&1&1&2\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$ is not consistent.

Comment: I guess the intent is to say that the result holds regardless of how many of the RREF rows are nonzero. This should be clear, as an all-zero row is certainly consistent.